# Nominal values for \parindent and other paragraph metrics

Tags: paragraphs, lengths, unit-of-measure

In memoir, when I run

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\showthe\parindent
\end{document}
```

I get:

```
17.62482 pt
```

My questions are :

1. Why that value? This number seems to capture something with high precision. Was it adjusted manually? If not, how do `memoir` or LaTeX compute it?
2. Is there a reference on what are "good-looking" values for parameters like `parindent`, `parskip`, etc?  What values are typically used/recommended?

Comment: The class itself sets those values and they are already set for what is considered "good-looking", but you can adjust them as desired.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The memoir class sets the `\parindent` to 15pt in one-column mode at 10pt size, to 17pt at 11pt size, to 1.5em (based on the default Computer Modern font) at 12pt size. In two-column mode the `\parindent` is always set to 1em (again based on the default Computer Modern font).

Usually 1em corresponds approximately to the font design size, so you get (slightly less than) 18pt in this case. Computer Modern em is a bit less than the design size at 12pt (Knuth's decision), but it's exactly 10pt for `cmr10`.

It's a designer's decision. For example, the parindent is smaller in two-column mode, to compensate for the reduced column width.

If you want to change it based on the actual font used in the document, the right place to do it is just after `\begin{document}`, unless you prefer an absolute dimension. But 1.5em or 1em can be considered standard.

Answer (score 11):

For documents using the `article` class, the default values of `\parindent`
depend on the `size` option and whether a `twocolumn` option is passed to
the document class:

```
|      | single | two     |
| size | column | columns |
|------+--------+---------|
|   10 | 15.0pt | 1em     |
|   11 | 17.0pt | 1em     |
|   12 |  1.5em | 1em     |
|------+--------+---------|
```

These dimensions are set in files `size10.clo`, `size11.clo` and
`size12.clo` which are located in the LaTeX source directory.

Why some are specified in points and other in ems is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 3):

The usual value of `\parindent` is `1em` (as used by `memoir` in some cases), with the intention of creating (considering line distances) a "visual square" of empty space.