# Changing indentation of pseudocode including line numbers with algorithm and algorithmic

Tags: indentation, algorithms, pseudocode

If I have pseudocode as shown below using the `algorithm` and `algorithmic` packages, is it possible to indent the pseudocode, including the line numbers, so that it lines up with the indentation of the first line of the paragraph above, i.e. so that the line numbers of the pseudocode are indented as much as the first line of the paragraph above.

[image]

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible solution via `adjustwidth` environment from `changepage` package. It takes two arguments.

As to the par indention value, please check [HERE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50138/34618)

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{left indent}{right indent}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
content
\end{algorithmic}
\end{adjustwidth}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,papersize={\paperwidth,8cm}]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[plain]{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{changepage}    %adjustwidth environment from changepage package


\begin{document}

Paragraph text, Paragraph text, Paragraph text, Paragraph text, Paragraph text, Paragraph text, Paragraph text, Paragraph text,

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{adjustwidth}{1em}{}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE{\textit{pollingDateTime $\leftarrow$ now $-$ 1 hour}}
\FOR {\textbf{each} rssFeed}
\STATE {\textit{pollingDateTime $\leftarrow$ now $-$ 1 hour}}
\ENDFOR 
\IF {\textit{pollingDateTime is even}}
\STATE {\textit{pollingDateTime $\leftarrow$ now $-$ 1 hour}}
\ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Algorithm 1}\label{alg1}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @MrMorgan, glad it helps.